# PHP operator -> and =>

Tags: php, yii

I am new to PHP, I want to know what difference between -> and => ?

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>
```

Comment: -> is calling a method, => is assigning a value to a key in an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-> is similar to `.` in java.
```

In simple words `->` is used for accessing the properties/methods of an object.

**Ex:-**

```
$model = new Foo();
$model->getArrowMeaning();
```

---

**On the other hand,** `=>` is used for assigning a value to a key in an array.

**Ex:-**

```
$foo = array(
'key'=>'value'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$model->isNewRecord()` invokes a method on an object (`$model` is an instance of a class and `isNewRecord()` is an instance method).

`array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')` is the syntax for associative array assignment, you are telling PHP to create an array with a key **'class'**, and an associated value **'btn btn-primary'**, if you had something like `$arr = array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')` then you could access the value with `$arr['class']`.

This is not Yii syntax, it's just plain PHP syntax.